# How to unit-test the responseType in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I have a method that dynamically sets responseType attribute of the $http request based on the asset type that's being requested. I'd like to unit-test that the correct response type is being set using Jasmine.

From what I found, you can expect a request with certain headers, but responseType is not a header, it's a part of the request config. Here are the samples of my code (in TypeScript).

```js
let config = {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': contentType
  }
}
if (contentType.startsWith('image')) {
  config.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
}
$http.get(url, config);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is a bit late, and I've spent quite a while on this, but I've finally gotten this to work.

Assuming you're reconstructing the $httpBackend in a beforeEach hook (mine's assigning it to a variable called 'backend'...  in the App config (or perhaps a more global beforeEach hook, haven't tried it that way), you'll need to add a decorator function to the $httpBackend service:

```
app.decorator('$httpBackend', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {

$delegate.interceptedCalls = [];
var $httpBackend = function (method, url, data, callback, headers, timeout, withCredentials, responseType,
                                         eventHandlers, uploadEventHandlers) {
    $delegate.interceptedCalls.push({
        method: method,
        url: url,
        timestamp: new Date(),
        type : responseType
    });
    return $delegate.apply(null, arguments);
};
    angular.extend($httpBackend, $delegate);
    return $httpBackend;
}]);
```

All that does is add an interceptedCalls property to your backend object which will contain a list of all the requests that go through it.

Then, in your test file, you can do something like this:

```
it("forwards the data correctly",function(){
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*'
        };

        backend.expectPOST('/someRoute/',{"A" : "B"},headers)
            .respond(200,"dsfkjlasdfasdfklsdfd");

        service.functionThatCallsSomeRoute({"A" : "B"});
        backend.flush();

        expect(backend.interceptedCalls[0]['type']).to.equal('arraybuffer');
 });
```

May not be the best way to do it, but since I'm essentially refreshing the whole thing (backend and service being tested) before every test, it will have all the calls in order on the object.